# Multiple IP for One Host

Tags: cluster-computing, globus-toolkit

I am setting up a grid-enabled cluster. I plan to assign 2 IP to my head node: one for local connection (LAN for distributing jobs to compute nodes) and one for public (internet for user access). So, my /etc/hosts file looks something like this:

```
111.111.111.111 myserver.whatever.com myserver #for public IP
11.11.11.11 myserver.whatever.com myserver #for local LAN
22.22.22.22 computenode01
33.33.33.33 computenode03
```

My concern here is will the hostname of myserver get messed up since it is mapped to two IPs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear the system will always choose the first entry (111.111.111.111) if you want to resolve "myserver" address.

Answer (score 0):

It will simply ignore the second entry, as I guess. Choose different hostnames for each entry, e.g. `myserver.local` and `myserver.remote`.